# What happened to the regex features?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

There used to be a feature in Luis called "Regex Features". You can still find it in google. Microsoft seems to have erased all evidence of it ever existing. 
Is it still supported in Luis? 
The Json for my Luis app still contains the regex features I made does Luis still use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote from [Microsoft LUIS Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-features)

> ### Pattern (regular expression) feature
>
> ---
>
> This feature is deprecated. New pattern features cannot be added to
>   LUIS. Any existing pattern features are supported until May 2018.
>   Contribute to standard LUIS regular expression matching with a Pull
>   Request to the [Recognizers-Text Github
>   repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text).

It seems to me that Microsoft has pulled away the Regular Expression features in LUIS. The only way to handle Regular Expressions in code is to clone and use their newly launched [Microsoft.Recognizers.Text](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text) project on GitHub by using the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Tex.git
cd Recognizers-Text
```

You can find its SDK reference [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/.NET#api-documentation).